# Tried to get user input while in a dialog box. InputText is read only it seem

Tags: xpages

I have some code, see below.  It's a dialog box that contains a list box for the user to select one or more choices and a text field to enter an email address.

When I put a viewScope variable as the value to capture the email address the field becomes like it's read only.  If I remove the value=viewScope..... the field shows as editable with a border etc.

How can I get the field to be editable and store the value in a scope variable for use when the click the submit button?

FYI, the list box works just fine.

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core" xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex"
xmlns:xc="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/custom">

<xp:panel id="panelJenarkCurrentYearReportsMain">
    <xp:panel id="panelJenarkCurrentYearReportsInner">
        <xe:dialog id="dialogCurrentReports" title="Fetch Current Year Reports">
            <xp:div styleClass="lotusMessage lotusInfo" role="alert">
                <xp:listBox id="listBoxJenarkCurrentYearReports" value="#{viewScope.jenarkCurrentYearReports}"
                    multiple="true" style="height:150.0px;width:98%;margin-left:5px"
                    required="true">
                    <xp:selectItems id="selectItems1">
                        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:var db = new Array( @DbName()[0], "dbWorkflow\\reference" );
result = @DbLookup(db, "($VSYSCTLKW)", "*ALL*ALL*ALLJenarkCurrentYearReports", "KWValues" );
if (result && typeof result == "string") 
result = new Array(result); 
return result; 
}]]></xp:this.value>
                    </xp:selectItems>
                    <xp:this.validators>
                        <xp:validateRequired
                            message="Please Select one or more Current Year Reports!" />
                    </xp:this.validators>
                </xp:listBox>
                <xp:panel>
                    <xp:label value="Send Reports To:"
                        id="labelJenarkReportsEmailTo"
                        style="width:20%;padding-left:3.0px;margin-left:3.0px">
                    </xp:label>
                </xp:panel>
                <xp:panel>
                <xp:inputText id="inputTextJenarkReportsEMailTo"
                    style="width:75%;padding-left:3.0px;margin-left:5.0px"
                    value="#{javascript:viewScope.jenarkReportEMail;}" required="true">
                    <xp:this.validators>
                        <xp:validateRequired
                            message="Please Enter a valid email Address!">
                        </xp:validateRequired>
                    </xp:this.validators>
                </xp:inputText>
                </xp:panel>
            </xp:div>
        </xe:dialog>
    </xp:panel>
</xp:panel>
</xp:view>
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your value definition to

```
value="#{viewScope.jenarkReportEMail}"
```

It has to be in Expression Language (EL). This way inputText control not just knows how to read viewScope variable's current value but also where to write user's input value to.

If you start your expression with `"#{javascript:..."` then it will execute the JavaScript code and insert the current value of `viewScope.jenarkReportEMail` as inputText's value. Just as a string, not as a variable where you can write to. That's why inputText can't write and shows itself as "read only".